# How to read integers to array from file

Tags: java, arrays

So, basically I want to learn how to read from file integers using methods and get the output - array to return. Does someone have an advice?

```java
static int[] readFromFile() {
    int[] data = new int[10];
    try {

        File myObj = new File("inputFile.txt");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                data[i] = myReader.nextInt();
            System.out.println(data);


        }
        myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(" .");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return data;
}
```

I want that code returns arrays with all integers from file

Comment: Looks like you already started on some pretty reasonable code, so: what's the problem?

Comment: Problem is that I need to read from file and get the output arrays but only what i can do get strings from txt file i didn't know how to simply get all info of integers

Comment: I think you want to return all integers, not just the first 10? In that case you could use a List, and cast it to an array before returning.

Comment: @S.L.Barth-ReinstateMonica No, i want to get only 10 numbers from the file.

Comment: It looks like your code does just that... what's going wrong? What happens when you try to read the file? Please [edit] it into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.  One is that you cannot change the size of an array.  You would have to reallocate a new array and copy if you want to resize it.
The other is that you have two loops going on.  Every invocation of the while loop will overwrite your array of 10 elements.

So let's try using ArrayList instead.  ArrayList lets you dynamically append more items onto the end.

Edit: you only want 10 integers:

```
static List<Integer> readFromFile() {
    List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        File myObj = new File("inputFile.txt");
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
        while (myReader.hasNext() && data.size() < 10) {
            data.add(myReader.nextInt());
        }
        myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(" .");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

If, at the end of all that, you really want to return an array instead of a list, you can use the `toArray()` method on `data`.

Comment: Java's best (and worst) contribution to this sort of thing is `java.util.stream.Stream` ... ***BEST*** in the sense that creating variable length lists, and converting to an `array` is really ***easy***.  However, ***WORST*** in the sense that some of the methods in `class Stream` are extremely difficult to understand....  Why not use `java.util.stream.IntStream.Builder`?  It's the same number of lines...  2 Pennies (2 cents).

Comment: Good thing you noticed the nested loop! @Dovis , if this answer solves your problem, you should click on the checkmark . That will signal that the problem is solved, and reward the answerer with some nice points. If not, please clarify the problem further.